# Delphi6 crash on close (Close all or terminate IDE)

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

I have a Delphi project that will always crash Delphi 6 IDE on either Close All or on exiting the IDE.

The only log I can get is this :

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   AppHangB1
  Application Name: delphi32.exe
  Application Version:  6.0.6.163
  Application Timestamp:    2a425e19
  Hang Signature:   aeb6
  Hang Type:    0
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Hang Signature 1:  aeb66c4f40472492607564cb689a3497
  Additional Hang Signature 2:  c023
  Additional Hang Signature 3:  c023b3065c42d81b672caef1f839eda0
  Additional Hang Signature 4:  aeb6
  Additional Hang Signature 5:  aeb66c4f40472492607564cb689a3497
  Additional Hang Signature 6:  c023
  Additional Hang Signature 7:  c023b3065c42d81b672caef1f839eda0
```

Is there something I can do to generate more log or a simpler way to compare this project with other Delphi project? The same project will crash different Delphi installation (same version on different PC)

Comment: Problems like this one are often caused by 3rd party components.  Do you use any in this project that you don't in ones which don't crash the IDE?

Comment: That's a good point. Nothing special in terms of 3rd party components for the 'buggy' project. I tried to remove all use and 3rd party declaration but the IDE still hangs on close. I also tried to copy the project configuration in totally new project, no luck to replicate the problem.

Comment: Well, if it's a problem of the sort I was thinking, the IDE would still likely hang/crash in the session that you remove the declarations. But, does it still happen in an IDE session started afresh after you've removed them?  Btw, you can "debug" the IDE to some extent by running it as an application inside another instance of it.  The host instance of the IDE should be able to catch what's happening and maybe give you a clue about what's causing it.

Comment: `madExcept` will also give you a call stack of any IDE crash, which will probably yield some useful information.

Comment: Just load an another instance in debugger and trigger a crash. It will at least give you an offending module name and at most a line number of bug.